# How do yo randomly assign a value to a variable?

Tags: java, string, variables, random

How do I assign a random value to a variable "myVariable" to either be "a", "b", or "c"? I was trying the following, but get several errors:

```
Random r = new Random();
String i = r.next()%33;
switch (i) {
  case 0:
    myVariable = "a";
  case 1:
    myVariable = "b";
  case 2:
    myVariable = "c";
}
```

Comment: Provide the necessary code to reproduce your exact errors. Also, don't forget to provide a default value to your variable.

Comment: I don't think `r.next()%33` returns a String.

Comment: Where's your size argument to r.next()? And no, it doesn't return a String, nor is your switch statement written to use a string. Read the javadoc?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use

```
r.nextInt(3);
```

to get a number from the range 0-2. So,

```
switch(r.nextInt(3)) {
  case 0: myVar = "a"; break;
  case 1: myVar = "b"; break;
  case 2: myVar = "c"; break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Normally, when it comes to a random number, I just check if it's within a range, for example..

```
Random random = new Random();
int output = random.next(100);

if(output > 0 && output < 33) {
    myVariable = "a";
}
else if(output >= 33 && output < 66) {
    myVariable = "b";
}
else {
    myVariable = "c";
}
```

This gives an *almost* equal probability to each value appearing.

Answer (score 0):

```
Random rand = new Random();
int min = 97; // ascii for 'a'
int randomNum = rand.nextInt(3) + min;
char myVariable = (char)randomNum;
```

Answer (score 0):

All good answers, but here's a different one:

```
class Randy {
    private final String[] POSSIBLE_VALUES = { "foo", "bar", "baz", ... };
    private final Random random = new Random();

    String getRandomValue() {
        return POSSIBLE_VALUES[random.nextInt(POSSIBLE_VALUES.length)];
    }
}
```